# How to re-run code from my if if else statement

Tags: android

I have 4 buttons with answers and would like to eliminate one of the buttons. I have a way of randomly choosing a button and I am using an if statement to determine if the selected button is in fact the actual answer as I do not want that button eliminated. The problem I am have is that there is a 1 in 4 chance of that button being chosen and so if it is chosen the I want the process to start again until the if condition is false.

```
    private int[] myInt;
    public static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
public void onClickEliminate(View view) {

    Resources res = getResources();
    myInt = res.getIntArray(R.array.ansArray);
    int ans = myInt[rgenerator.nextInt(myInt.length)];

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(ans);
    CharSequence message = button.getText().toString();

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correct);
    CharSequence answer = textview.getText().toString();

    if (message.equals(answer)) {
    // Here I need the above process to run again
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Keep this button");
    } else { 
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Button gone");
    }
}
```

I realise that this will need to be run on a back thread but I am just looking at basic functionality at present. Is there anyone out there who can help please. Kind regards, Derek

ps: I have already tried to use loops but they are either ineffective or infinite. I thought that by using Random that the value for "message" should change at some stage.

Comment: If you want to execute some code several times put it into a loop. Since this is very basic programming knowledge, you may want to work through some tutorials.

Comment: put the code you want to repeat inside a method and then you can execute it whenever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
boolean myprocess = true;

while(myprocess){
    if (message.equals(answer)) {
       // Here I need the above process to run again
       Log.i(LOGTAG, "Keep this button");
   } else { 
        myprocess = false;
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Button gone");
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice endless loop, if `message.equals(answer)` what would make it change?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have added a bit more information that I hope may make it clearer to what I'm trying to achieve.